# What are the differences between Windows 7 versions?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, .net-framework

There are the following versions of Windows 7:

- Windows 7 Starter
- Windows 7 Home Basic
- Windows 7 Home Premium
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 7 Ultimate

I know about the following restrictions:

- Starter is missing Aero and restricts wallpaper changing.
- Home Basic restricts some Aero Features.

Can someone specify any other differences?   Are there any ways to circumvent the restrictions?  If so, are they legal?

Additionally, I would like to know about .NET development in general.  What is the minimum version required to develop using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure SuperUser.com administrators do NOT want us posting methods that would help you violate licensing... so I'm not going there.  If you are looking for a feature comparison, Paul Thurrott's is probably the best one I've seen - see: 
http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/windows-7-product-editions-a-comparison-128684

As for the minimum version to develop with ASP.NET is a web programming language and TECHNICALLY, you could develop in it using Notepad.  If you want to use Visual Studio, then the question is which version of Visual Studio do you want to use?  Then check the product requirements (if it won't run on Windows 7 Starter, for example, it should say so).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a page describing the various Windows 7 editions and their features: [**Windows 7 editions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions).

There should not be any restriction in developing with .Net.

I don't know if there are ways to circumvents some limitations but I highly doubt it's legal.